Download file on submission of HTML form
I want to implement a website that prompts the user to fill out an HTML form. When the user clicks the submit button, the form's data is sent URL encoded to the server. The server then processes the data and generates a document with it that the user's browser shall then download.
So far, I achieved this behaviour by responding to the form submission with an HTTP response which has the header field Content-Disposition attachment.
If my reading of Section 19.5.1 of the HTTP/1.1 specification is correct, the Content-Disposition field is not required by the standard. The same document also states certain security concerns regarding this field.
Is there some more standard/elegant method to solve my problem? I wanted to avoid a two-step solution (first button only sends, second button downloads the file) as this would require the server to store the data which would introduce increased complexity to such a simple problem. For the same reason I also tried to avoid JavaScript.
There is also the issue that if I wanted to provide a new page stating, "Thank you for your submission, your file is downloading now." I would not be able to do that, as I can either send the file to download or a new page.
